# Arabia and the Middle Ages

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Kind of direct language; used in the Middle Ages (8)
>   8. Stadiums are small beyond the limits of NBA (6)
>   9. A blowgun destroyed small house (8)
>   10. Frog King decapitated a kind of crab (6)
>   13. In Arabia, spirit of radio host appearing near tavern (5)
>   14. Never tell him the odds (so low!) on the radio (4)
>   15. In *The X-Files*, Scully planned an attack in secret (4)
>   16. Cave-dwellers hit with knife from behind (4)
>   18. Greek Goddess's rise misinterpreted (4)
>   19. The main part of military formation over the air (4)
>   20. Care about covering space (4)
>   23. *Rolling Stone* making remarks (5)
>   25. Preacher's talk of horrible omens being about right (6)
>   26. Like Violet and Amber, Terry has aunt in Mexico (8)
>   27. Revolution to erase a country's clandestine ruler (6)
>   28. Sycophants are close to rulers in part of Arabia (3, 3)
>
> **Down**
>   2. Bullet's shape (5)
>   3. Heads of poles seen after going out (7)
>   4. Perhaps the Solomon Islands duly constrain flying (6, 7)
>   5. Peddling some kind of greeny mass, in a relative sense (7, 6)
>   6. Support South Chicago's footballers (5)
>   7. Last of herb as one additional, finishing ingredient in pesto sauce (5)
>   11. In the Middle Ages, Arab striking heart of Sauron's realm (4)
>   12. From the south, identify peaks (4)
>   16. Unfairness starts to become increasingly apparent before the end of elections (4)
>   17. Category of heartless predator (4)
>   18. The case of eleven attempts to get permissions to go in (7)
>   21. Royal Brewery's product knocked back (5)
>   22. Collect from a man with donkey (5)
>   24. Deliver flowing verse (5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Complete crossword

[image: finished!]

**Clue explanations - across**

1. Kind of direct language; used in the Middle Ages (8)

> FRANKISH (double def "kind of direct" and "language used in the Middle Ages"). **Very clever clue!**

8. Stadiums are small beyond the limits of NBA (6)

> ARENAS (def "stadiums", first ARE followed by S for small beyond the ends of NbA).

9. A blowgun destroyed small house (8)

> BUNGALOW (def "small house", anagram [destroyed] of "a blowgun"). Thanks @OmegaKrypton!

10. Frog King decapitated a kind of crab (6)

> KERMIT (def "frog", K for "King" added to HERMIT, "a kind of crab", decapitated).

13. In Arabia, spirit of radio host appearing near tavern (5)

> DJINN (def "in Arabia, spirit"; sounds [on the radio] like gin which is a spirit found in a tavern, or DJ followed by INN).

14. Never tell him the odds (so low!) on the radio (4)

> SOLO (sounds [on the radio] like "so low"; I guess "never tell him the odds" refers to Han Solo?)

15. In The X-Files, Scully planned an attack in secret (4)

> DANA (def "in the X-Files, Scully"; appears [in secret] in "planneD AN Attack").

16. Cave-dwellers hit with knife from behind (4)

> BATS (def "cave-dwellers"; reversed STAB or "hit with knife")

18. Greek Goddess's rise misinterpreted (4)

> ERIS (def "Greek goddess"; anagram of RISE).

19. The main part of military formation over the air (4)

> CORE (def "main part"; homophone ["over the air"] of CORPS = military unit).

20. Care about covering space (4)

> AREA (def "space"; appears in "cARE About").

23. Rolling Stone making remarks (5)

> NOTES (def "remarks"; anagram of STONE).

25. Preacher's talk of horrible omens being about right (6)

> SERMON (def "preacher's talk"; anagram of OMENS around R for right).

26. Like Violet and Amber, Terry has aunt in Mexico (8)

> TERTIARY (def "like Violet and Amber", which are apparently [tertiary colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_color); TIA is Spanish for "aunt", in the middle of TERRY). Thanks @Jens!

27. Revolution to erase a country's clandestine ruler (6)

> CAESAR ("revolution" as in Caesar shift, "ruler" also def, appears in "eRASE A Country's").

28. Sycophants are close to rulers in part of Arabia (3, 3)

> YES MEN (def "sycophants", YEMEN is part of Arabia). Thanks @OmegaKrypton!

**Clue explanations - down**

2. Bullet's shape (5)

> ROUND (double def). Thanks @OmegaKrypton!

3. Heads of poles seen after going out (6)

> NOGGINS (def "heads", ends of SeeN after anagram of GOING). Thanks @hexomino!

4. Perhaps the Solomon Islands duly constrain flying (6, 7)

> ISLAND COUNTRY (def "perhaps the Solomon Islands", anagram of "duly constrain").

5. Peddling some kind of greeny mass, in a relative sense (7, 6)

> HAWKING ENERGY (def "mass in a relative sense"; "peddling" = HAWKING, "greeny" anagram of ENERGY).

6. Support South Chicago's footballers (5)

> BEARS (double def: "support South" and "Chicago's footballers").

7. Last of herb as one additional, finishing ingredient in pesto sauce (5)

> BASIL (def "finishing ingredient in pesto sauce"; last letter of "herB" followed by AS followed by I = one followed by last letter of "additionaL").

11. In the Middle Ages, Arab striking heart of Sauron's realm (4)

> MOOR (def "in the Middle Ages, Arab"; "Sauron's realm" is MORDOR).

12. From the south, identify peaks (4)

> TOPS (def "peaks", identify = SPOT backwards). Thanks @OmegaKrypton!

16. Unfairness starts to become increasingly apparent before the end of elections (4)

> BIAS (def "unfairness", starts of "Become Increasingly Apparent" before end of "electionS").

17. Category of heartless predator (4)

> TIER (def "category", heartless TIGER). Thanks @OmegaKrypton!

18. The case of eleven attempts to get permissions to go in (7)

> ENTRIES (def "permissions to go in"; outer letters or "case" of EleveN, followed by "attempts to get" = TRIES). Thanks @OmegaKrypton!

21. Royal Brewery's product knocked back (5)

> REGAL (def "royal", reverse "brewery's product" = LAGER).

22. Collect from a man with donkey (5)

> AMASS (def "collect", AM from "a man", donkey = ASS).

24. Deliver flowing verse (5)

> SERVE (def "deliver", anagram of "verse).

---

**[Partial solution *without* using Omega Krypton's answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgqW7.png)**. After getting this far, I used OK's solutions for 9, 28 across and 2, 12, 17, 18 down, since he said "feel free to use". Just wanted to record how far I got without any help.

---

**Feedback section:** this was fun to solve. The easiest clue for me was 24 down, followed by 22 across. Then I gradually put things together starting from the bottom left. The hardest clues were 1, 19, 26 across and 3 down. For both of the massive clues (4 and 5 down), I got one word first (ISLAND and ENERGY) and filled that in because I was pretty sure about it, long before finding the other half of the clue.

Comment: 3 down must be rot13(ABTTVAF = nantenz TBVAT + FrrA)

Comment: I suspect 26 is ROT13(Gre-gvn-el, nf Gvn vf Nhag va Fcnavfu)

Comment: Also 1 across is probably rot13(SENAX-VFU )

Comment: @hexomino not rot13(FrrA) but rot13(cbyrf).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Aw yeah, you're right, that makes more sense.

Comment: (and agree about 1ac)

Comment: Thanks @hexomino! (For the record, I finished the grid after seeing just your first comment solving 3 down, figuring out both 1 across and what Tnergu ZpPnhtuna said.)

Comment: @wl Doh. "Over the air" to clue homophones - unexpected but neat!

Comment: @wl Would be much easier if you didn't Rot13 all these comments. Is anyone going to scroll down through a big long answer to get spoiled by explanations in the comments?

Comment: Thanks for the help though! Good eye on all those clues.

Answer (score 3):

### Had to sleep, feel free to use this partial... Solutions (Not spoilered)

Across
9 *BUNGALOW
18 *ERIS
20 _AREA_
23 *NOTES
25 *SE(R)MON
27 >_CEASAR_
28 YE(_S) MEN

Down
2 ROUND (ddef)
12 >TOPS
17 TI(-g)ER
18 E_N+TRIES
21 REGAL<
22 A+M+ASS
24 *SERVE

Comment: 20,000 rep exactly ... I can't upvote.

Comment: Feel free, I've screenshot it, moving towards 30k @Randal'Thor +1

Comment: OK, now done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got them all but 19A.

SOMEONE FIX MY SPOILERS!

ACROSS

> ! 1. Kind of direct language; used in the Middle Ages (8) FRANKISH dd
>   8. Stadiums are small beyond the limits of NBA (6) ARE_NA_S
>   9. A blowgun destroyed small house (8) BUNGALOW*
>   10. Frog King decapitated a kind of crab (6) K+ERMIT
>   13. In Arabia, spirit of radio host appearing near tavern (5) DJ+INN
>   14. Never tell him the odds (so low!) on the radio (4)  SOLO (homophone)
>   15. In The X-Files, Scully planned an attack in secret (4) planne_D AN A_ttack
>   16. Cave-dwellers hit with knife from behind (4) BATS<
>   18. Greek Goddess's rise misinterpreted (4) ERIS*
>   19. The main part of military formation over the air (4)
>   20. Care about covering space (4) A+RE+A
>   23. Rolling Stone making remarks (5) NOTES*
>   25. Preacher's talk of horrible omens being about right (6) SE(R)MON*
>   26. Like Violet and Amber, Terry has aunt in Mexico (8) TER(TIA)RY
>   27. Revolution to erase a country's clandestine ruler (6) C+AESER*
>   28. Sycophants are close to rulers in part of Arabia (3, 3)  YES MEN  S - close to rulerS in YEMEN,

Down

> !
>   2. Bullet's shape (5)  ROUND dd
>   3. Heads of poles seen after going out (7) NOGGI* + NS???
>   4. Perhaps the Solomon Islands duly constrain flying (6, 7) ISLAND COUNTRY*
>   5. Peddling some kind of greeny mass, in a relative sense (7, 6) HAWKING + ENERGY*
>   6. Support South Chicago's footballers (5) BEARS dd
>   7. Last of herb as one additional, finishing ingredient in pesto sauce (5)B_AS_I_L
>   11. In the Middle Ages, Arab striking heart of Sauron's realm (4) MOOR ( from MO_rd_OR)
>   12. From the south, identify peaks (4)  TOPS<
>   16. Unfairness starts to become increasingly apparent before the end of elections (4)
>    BIAS (starts to Become Increasingly Apparent +S)
>   17. Category of heartless predator (4) TIER (Tiger -g)
>   18. The case of eleven attempts to get permissions to go in (7) E-leve-N +TRIES
>   21. Royal Brewery's product knocked back (5) REGAL<
>   22. Collect from a man with donkey (5)A+M+ASS
>   24. Deliver flowing verse (5) SERVE*